# Copy Range from multiple workbooks in folder to Summary Workbook also in folder?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a folder with 100+ workbooks.  These workbooks contain a range of data.  For simplicity I will call the data range A1:D2, the range is located on Sheet1 of all 100+ workbooks.

I also have a Summary workbook.

I would like to place VBA code in the Summary workbook that loops through the folder, copying the range A1:D2 of each of the 100+ workbooks.

I would then like to paste the A1:D2 range from each workbook in to Sheet1 of the Summary workbook.  Each paste will start on the next unused row.

I am stuck doing this via a manual process right now and it is driving me insane.

I do know some basic VBA coding however my problem is that I can't figure out how to loop it correctly, and I am stuck coding each individual workbook to open-->copy-->paste-->close.  This was fine with 10-20 workbooks but now I am at 100+ and it is growing every week.

Thanks again,

Brian

Comment: Use the macro recorder to create the code to do it once - then create some looping logic and see how it goes - post what you end up with here and tell us where it doesn't work.

Comment: Edit your question and include the things you've tried (especially the code). Then specifically point out the part you're having issues.

Answer (score 0):

I have something that does exactly what you are asking for, if you want to copy multiple workbooks I suggest creating a new worksheet to capture the workbook information onto a spreadsheet.  Instructions below

1. Create a new worksheet and give it a name, in this case we'll call the sheet 'Control'
2. Create a new module in VBA and use the code below to operate the workbook copy

I have left a section out for you to write your code for the functions that you want to perform.

Sub WorkbookConsolidator()

```
Dim WB As Workbook, wb1 as workbook
Dim WBName as Range 
Dim folderselect as Variant, wbA as Variant, wbB as Variant, 
Dim I as long, J as long
Dim objFolder As Object, objFile As Object
Dim WBRange as String

'Set Core Variables and Open Folder containing workbooks.

 Set WB = ThisWorkbook
 Worksheets("Control").Activate
 Set FolderSelect = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
 FolderSelect.AllowMultiSelect = False
 MsgBox ("Please Select the Folder containing your Workbooks")
 FolderSelect.Show
 WBRange = FolderSelect.SelectedItems(1)
 Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(FolderSelect.SelectedItems(1))


' Fill out File name Fields in Control Sheet 
' The workbook names will be captured in Column B
' This allows allocation for up to 100 workbooks
For I = 1 To 100
    For Each objFile In objFolder.files
    If objFile = "" Then Exit For
       Cells(I, 2) = objFile.Name ' Workbook Name
       Cells(I, 3) = WBRange ' Workbook Path
       I = I + 1
       Next objFile
    Next I

'Loop through the list of workbooks created in the 'Control' Directory, adjust the loop range as preferred
For J = 100 To 1 Step -1
      With Workbooks(ThisWorkbook).Worksheets("Control")
         BookLocation = .Range("C" & J).Value
         BookName = .Range("B" & J).Value
      End With

    Set wb1 = Workbooks.Open(Booklocation & Bookname)

    ' Write your code here'



       CleanUp:
       wb1.Close SaveChanges:=False

Next J

End Sub()
```

`

Comment: Thank you, I'll test this out over the weekend and see how it does.  Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Sub combine_into_one()
Dim FSO As Object: Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim strPath$, Pivot$, sUserName$, sFolderName$, sSourceName$, x&
Dim oFldialog As FileDialog
Dim oFile As Scripting.File
Dim oFolder

Set oFldialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

With oFldialog
    If .Show = -1 Then
        .Title = "Select a Folder"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .InitialFileName = strPath
        sFolderName = .SelectedItems(1)
    End If
End With

Set oFolder = FSO.GetFolder(sFolderName)

Workbooks.Add: Pivot = ActiveWorkbook.Name 'Destination workbook

For Each oFile In oFolder.Files
    Workbooks(Pivot).Activate

    x = Workbooks(Pivot).Sheets("Sheet1").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row + 1

    Workbooks.Open filename:=oFile: sSourceName = ActiveWorkbook.Name
    Workbooks(sSourceName).Activate
        Workbooks(sSourceName).Sheets("Sheet1").[A1:D1].Copy

    Workbooks(Pivot).Activate
    Workbooks(Pivot).Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(x, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
    Workbooks(sSourceName).Close False
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you---I'll work on this over the weekend and see how it does.